# How do I .gitignore and delete an already committed file without affecting other working copies?

Tags: git, file, gitignore, delete-file

I have a bare repository and two working copies - one on my machine, the other on the server.
It turned out that I have to `.gitignore` a certain file that has to be specific for every machine. Let's call it '`settings.py`'. This file is already committed.

I did put '`settings.py`' in .gitignore to ignore it. When I now change the file on my machine git status still tells me

```
modified:  settings.py
```

I figured out that I have to remove settings.py like this:

```
git rm --cached settings.py
```

Then `git add .`, followed by `git commit`.

But when I now push this to the bare repo and pull it to the working copy on the server, `settings.py` is deleted there - which is bad because I have to keep this specific `settings.py`.

I figured that I just could make a copy of `settings.py` and put it back in once it is deleted, but I feel like there has to be a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can tell git to completely ignore changes to tracked files without having to remove them.  Use this command:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged [FILENAME]
```

Then if you want to track the file later:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged [FILENAME]
```

Answer (score 7):

Could you rather keep settings.py deleted permanently (both locally and on remote), and:

- version a `setting_remote` file for the remote side
- version a `setting_local` file for the local side (ie with local specific settings)
- add a **[filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316677/can-git-automatically-switch-between-spaces-and-tabs/2316728#2316728)** able to rebuild the right `settings.py` file on checkout.

[image]

That way, `settings.py` is kept "private" (non-versioned). But the specific values for each environment are versioned, each set in its own file, without any merging issue.