# prevent git checkout from overwriting a file

Tags: linux, git

Another dev checked his .rvmrc into the git repo.  I've since removed it and added it to gitignore, but every time in need to go back in time it overwrites my .rvmrc.  I'm on OSX, so I've discovered I can use the OSX file locking mechanism ("Locked" checkbox in Get Info) to stop this happening on my dev machine, but how would this be done on Linux?

I chown'd it to root and chmod'd it to 444, yet git (run as my normal user), somehow transcends the need for ownership & permission and still overwrites the file.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833757/how-do-i-gitignore-and-delete-an-already-commited-file-without-affecting-other-w

Answer (score 4):

Ironically, while git’s default behavior is to treat untracked files as precious, adding the file to `.gitignore` tells git that it can trash the file whenever it wants.

Entries in `.gitignore` are more commonly used to indicate generated files, and as such git will overwrite them silently. Entries in `.git/info/exclude` are perhaps supposed to be used for local versions of configuration files.

Please read [this discussion](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/153700) in its entirety, as there seems to be some confusion as to the difference between the two. I just tried this out, and entries in `.git/info/exclude` are protected when you go back in time, producing "error: Untracked working tree file '.rvmrc' would be overwritten by merge." This different behavior between the two might not be deliberate, according to Junio C Hamano. However, if you can remove the entry from `.gitignore` and move it to `.git/info/exclude`, you might be able to make this work, realizing that the latter is not versioned or shared between repositories and would require manual cooperation with your colleague.

As for the permissions issue, see this:

```
$ touch foo
$ ls -l foo
-rw-r--r--  1 josh  staff  0 Oct  1 09:55 foo
$ sudo chown root:wheel foo
$ ls -l foo
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  0 Oct  1 09:55 foo
$ unlink foo
$ ls -l foo
ls: foo: No such file or directory
```

In Unix, the ability to create or remove a file is based only on the permissions of the *directory* that contains it. Permissions on the file itself are only for modifications to the file (unfortunately in your case). The `rm` utility checks permissions on the file as a courtesy, but `unlink` is lower-level and blindly calls the system call.

Comment: Thank you for the very comprehensive and detailed answer.

However, unfortunately I just get the message "error: Untracked working tree file '.rvmrc' would be overwritten by merge." and I can't checkout the old commit.

Comment: @Tim Oh, that is a problem. The only thing I can think of is using a [filter](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html#_tt_filter_tt) to modify the file after checkout, or using [filter-branch](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html) to rewrite history to get rid of it.