# gitignore continue to track file after adding it once by force

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a file mentioned in .gitignore, but I added it by `git add -f` because I wanted to add 
it only once and then ignore it as usual.

However, it is now tracked by default. How do I undo this?

Answer (score 11):

Not completely sure what you're looking for but you can either remove the file to be ignored in future commits with

```
git rm --cached filename
```

> *Note that git will not ignore a file that was already tracked before a
>   rule was added to this file to ignore it. In such a case the file must
>   be un-tracked, usually with git rm --cached filename*

Info: https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files

Or you can tell git that it ignores the changes of a file with

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged filename
```

and undo it with

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged filename
```

To list all assume-unchanged files run

```
git ls-files -v|grep '^h'
```

Info: [How do I .gitignore and delete an already committed file without affecting other working copies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833757/how-do-i-gitignore-and-delete-an-already-commited-file-without-affecting-other)

However please keep in mind that assume-unchanged is (in my opinion) against the philosophy of git and this command will only ignore it the changes made on your machine. Everyone else will still be able to overwrite it.

In most cases you use this for configuration files. What you can do to avoid using this option is to keep it in the .gitignore and add a setup description to the README or create a little setup script which creates those files.

Comment: I did `git rm --cached filename` now `git status` shows  

    Changes to be committed:
    #   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage) 
    #
    # deleted:    main/filename

Comment: Yes from now on git will ignore main/filename

Comment: `Not completely sure what you're looking for` - Just for some context for anyone else that might read this: this is useful if you want to have a configuration file with a blank template that users can download, but not commit sensitive information. At least, that's one reason why I came here looking to understand how to do this in git.

Comment: @joseph4tw I always place a "sample-config" in the repo instead of using assume-unchanged. (e.g. .env_sample and .env, config_sample.php and config.php) It's a hassle if you want to add configuration parameters and always have to update this file.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove it with...

```
git rm --cached file
```

Then commit.